# View goes transparent when presentViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I wrote my code like this

```
- (void)menuButtonClick:(id)sender{
    ViewController *test = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:test];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But I discover that the view goes transparent when moving into the screen. The view turns to white as it should be after the animation.

like this.
**If the GIF is not playing, please open it in a new tab.**
[image]

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: set your ViewController background color is white color.

Comment: you should use `ViewController *test = [[ViewController alloc] init];` instead of  `ViewController *test = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`